# Is there an alternative to map() that modifies the original list

Tags: python, foreach

With the way that `map()` is designed it seems like it is intended to be used specifically when you are trying to return modified COPY of a list. I am wondering if there is an alternative to map() that is designed specifically for when you do want to modify the original list rather then returning a modified copy. Here is an example:

```
def addition(n):
    return n + n
  
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = map(addition, numbers)
print(result)
output : [2, 4, 6, 8]
print(numbers)
output : [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is how it would look using map, but what is stored in result is a copy, and not the original list. Is there a python method that modifies the original list items so that if I print(numbers) the original list would be modified?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? It seems that you are just duplicating boilerplate logic of a `ModelForm`.

Comment: Its just an example. I am not looking for a solution for the specific code i pasted. I want a general response on if there is an alternative to map() that doesn't return a list of modified objects. I want to modify multiple things and return nothing.

Comment: I added an example of what the for loop could look like.

Comment: It's very unclear what problem you're trying to solve. Python is not very FP-oriented language, so you shouldn't expect smth like rust's `my_collection.iter().for_each(|item| ...)` - plain `for` loop is sufficient. What exactly is wrong with a loop in your use case?

Comment: What I think you're looking for is `list(map(...))` (the `list()` call will consume the `map` iterable), but a simple `for` loop is considered more idiomatic for this use case.

Comment: Thanks. Thats all I was looking for is if there is a built in function similar to map that doesn't return anything. Hence both sentences ending with a ? are asking that exact thing. @SUTerliakov

Comment: @JoeV Please read this article about [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - I'm asking about the actual problem, because it's very unlikely that your desire is useful and should be applied somewhere.

Comment: However, personally I'd go with the following update, maybe: `self.initial |= {attr: getattr(self.instance, attr) for attr in attrs if getattr(self.instance, attr, None) not in {None, ""}}` (and certainly get rid of `hasattr + getattr` in nested `if`'s: `if` does short-circuit in python, so no need to nest, plus `getattr(obj, name, default)` doesn't raise - you check for `None` anyway later).

Comment: "an alternative to map() that doesn't return a list" - Well, map() doesn't return a list.

Comment: @KellyBundy An iterable. My OP is asking for a method that doesn't return anything.

Comment: That's impossible. (Well, unless you want it to raise an exception, in which case it really doesn't return anything. Or if it has an infinite loop, then it also doesn't return anything. But neither seem like a good idea.)

Comment: Not returning anything, i.e., just having side effects, doesn't sound like the "fp way" to me...

Comment: Now that I can understand. I am clearly not a functional programmer as I am writing python. Are void functions not a thing in fp at all then? You are strictly always creating copies if you are doing a functional approach?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I can see the confusion in my question then. As what I am looking for probably doesn't fall in the category of "functional programming". I was simply wondering if there is a built in python function that works similar to map, but is meant to modify the list and not return a modified copy.

Comment: There are different flavors/opinions of functional programming, but I think it at least would be untypical (I'm no fp expert, though). The "modify the list" is something else again. I'd expect that to be a method of the `list` class. I think I've actually seen a feature request for that.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Understood, thanks for bearing with me. Updated the question thanks to your feedback hopefully it is more explanatory now.